# java: create runtime a pojo object from a properties file

Tags: java, reflection, drools, pojo

Within a java project, I would like that my system to create runtime  an object (POJO) from a configuration file and then use it in a drools-based system.
Point to be noted here is that the pojo class too should be generated at runtime
If I understand this is the only way to make controls on a data structure that does not have a fixed structure
What is the best way to do this?
It would be interesting to be able to cache the java class obtained so you do not have to create it all the time but only when the property file changes
Can someone help me ? 
I'm a bit confused 
Thank you so much

Comment: You might easily create a Java source file (e.g., from an XML Schema), and compile it into a class file, all "at runtime". But how are you going to write any rules "at runtime"? Are you barking up the right tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dynamically define your drl rule file.  In that file you can define types.  e.g.

```
declare MyEvent
   MyType : String
   MyValue : double
end
```

So after you have created the drl file contents from your properties file see `KieFileSystem` for loading up the drl file from memory.
This will create a POJO that you can then access using `kieContainer.getKieBase().getFactType` to get the type and then you can create an instance and set properties on it.

Comment: Great !! but can I fill FactType dynamically? For example, with a string array?I would not change the code every time I change the drl file.Thanks a lot

Comment: @GianPiero That's the first indication that you may not have analysed your situation thoroughly, and we aren't even discussing rule authoring.

Comment: You would need to build logic into your code that fills the FactTyoe using the information from your properties file. If you are supporting multiple data types then you might need some case statements to convert your incoming data to the correct type.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do it is hard to answer.